# Salesforce-send API Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api

We are trying to create a Salesforce-send using APIs. We want to use Salesforce standard reports as audience but when we perform the SOAP request we get this error:

```
V5 Customers cannot create User-Initiated Sends with Salesforce Reports or Campaigns
```

I understood that we have to create a Salesforce-send and i'm using the SalesforceSend API Object but i still get that error even if i'm not creating a user-initiated email.

Is there something that we have to get enabled by Salesforce support or should we use a different API call to create it?